# SQL Server - something available to practice dev for beginner

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, emulation

So this might be a ridiculous question, but I don't know so that is why I am asking:

I would like to practice some C#, and get some basic familiarity with the IDE for SQL Server. Is there some fake version of SQL server that I can download to practive with??

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need anything fake - just get the express editions - they're the real deal!

http://www.microsoft.com/Express/SQL/

http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/

Answer (score 3):

You can download Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition and SQL Server 2008 Express Edition.

[Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=f3fbb04e-92c2-4701-b4ba-92e26e408569)

[SQL Server 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7522a683-4cb2-454e-b908-e805e9bd4e28)

Answer (score 1):

You can download 180 day trial here 
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/default.aspx

AdventureWorks database is available for download as well if you're interested